# My application is unusely creating huge data when debugging the app in android studio

Tags: android

when I'm trying to build the application, Both release and debug are creating huge data(in MB).[this is my gradle file. I have created a new project and nothing is been created in it but still producing 2-3 MB..] 
can anyone please help me out?

[image]

Comment: are you using drawables in your layout. if yes this may be the case of increased apk size.

Comment: what do you mean by `huge data(in MB).`? Which data?

Comment: No, I have not pasted anything in my project...i have just created it newly and after that i build it...It is creating the apk of 2.5 MB

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the dependencies libraries especially the support libraries. If you create your application without the support libraries, your application will not weight about 1 MB. Which means you need to use `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` and use ListView instead of RecyclerView and etc.

Your basic application with support libraries will be weight about > 2 MB this is the trade-off of all the features support libraries gives you.

Answer (score 0):

*Update:*

Also delete one or more of these to save some space if you don't use them: glide,circle image view, cardview, constraint layout

*end Update*

This is basic support library size, maybe you are using some drawable which has some size of around 1MB.

Anyways, you can reduct apk size by shrinking resources and enabling minify.

app/build.gradle

```
android{
.
.
buildTypes {
    debug {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```